# Add 1 year to a date

Tags: php, date

I have a date 01/31/2014, and I need to add a year to it and make it 01/31/2015. I am using

```
$xdate1 = 01/31/2014;
$xpire = strtotime(date("m/d/Y", strtotime($xdate1)) . " +1 year");
```

But it is returning 31474800.

Comment: Please use the [search function](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+add+year) before asking a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Waaaay too complicated. You're doing multiple date<->string conversions, when

```
php > $x = strtotime('01/31/2014 +1 year');
php > echo date('m/d/Y', $x);
01/31/2015
```

would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is below:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2014-01-31');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P01Y'));
echo $date->getTimestamp();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes here.
You are missing the quote sign `"` when assigning to `$xdate1`. It should be

```
$xdate1 = "01/31/2014";
```

And the second, to get "01/31/2015", use the `date` function. `strtotime` returns a timestamp, not a date format. Therefore, use

```
$xpire = date("m/d/Y", strtotime(date("m/d/Y", strtotime($xdate1)) . " +1 year"));
```

Comment: yeah, the quote sign is simply me just trying to make it simple, I just wanted to show how the day appears in the variable. Its not really like this in my code, it pulls the date from MySQL. I truly appreciate the help, this worked.

Comment: if this date is coming out of mysql, then do the date math there: `SELECT yourdatefield + INTERVAL 1 YEAR`.

Answer (score 0):

May I introduce [a simple API extension for DateTime with PHP 5.3+](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon):

```
$xdate1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '01/31/2014');
$xpire = $xdate1->addYear(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First make $xdate1 as string value like

```
$xdate1 = '01/31/2014';
```

then apply date function at it like bellow

```
$xpire = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($xdate1.' +1 year')); // 01/31/2015
```